# start app automatically at reboot

Tags: google-pixel

I have an old-ish Google Pixel (gen1) phone that must have a hardware issue, and crashes/reboots every once in a while (every hour or so). It's unusable as a proper  phone but I thought I could reuse it as a single app kiosk-style screen. For example, I could have my Google Photo Albums displayed or I could use it as a stock ticker.

Is there a way to make a specific app start and take over the screen on reboot for Android?

Comment: I think my [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209595/247431) can be helpful. Just skip the step about splitting the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to accomplish with automation. Using [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) to demonstrate how to do it:

1. Select the Broadcast Receive block. Click on it, in the Action section, select "Boot completed". Click Done.
2. Select App Start block. Click on it, in the Package section, select the first app you wish to start at boot. Click Done.
3. Save and give it a name. Link the blocks as seen on the image below.
4. In the Settings, select "Run on system startup".
5. Don't forget to give the necessary permissions when asked. Press start.

Every time you reboot your device, after the boot has been completed, the app will be launched.